# Hydrolysis of magnesium boride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, boron-family

Does magnesium boride react with water to form boranes?

My attempt:

Magnesium nitride reacts with water to form ammonia and magnesium hydroxide.

Similarly, does magnesium boride also react with water to form a borane and magnesium hydroxide?

Answer (score 1):

Hydrolysis of magnesium boride has previously been attempted<sup>1</sup>. Two hydrolysis products were observed. The main hydrolysis product was found to be $\ce{Mg3B2(OH)6}$ but  at $\pu{-10 ^\circ C}$, a different product is formed whose composition was found to be $\ce{H3B2(MgOH)3}$ which immediately converts back to the main product if the temperature were slightly increased. The corresponding reactions were:

$$\ce{Mg3B2 + 6H2O -> Mg3B2(OH)6 + 3H2}$$
$$\ce{Mg3B2 + 3H2O -> H3B2(MgOH)3}$$
$$\ce{H3B2(MgOH)3 + 3H2O -> Mg3B2(OH)6 + 3H2}$$

No boric acid, magnesium borate or even boranes were formed although these products were expected from the hydrolysis reaction.

**Reference**

1. The hydrolysis of magnesium boride by Rames C. Ray  and  Prafulla C. Sinha , J. Chem. Soc., **1935**, 1694-1695, DOI: [10.1039/JR9350001694](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1935/jr/jr9350001694#!divAbstract) ([PDF](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/1935/jr/jr9350001694))

Comment: The compound $\ce{Mg_3B_2(OH)_6}$ seems to be made of $3$ $\ce{Mg(OH)_2}$ + $2$ atoms of elementary Boron. It looks as if Boron had been oxidized from $-3$ to $0$. Strange reaction ! Everything looks as if both Mg and B are at the oxidation number of zero in magnesium boride !!! Never seen such a strange reaction !

Comment: Are there other borides which gets hydrolsed to form boranes?

Comment: @NevilleVempeny Not that I know of, but action of dilute acids on magnesium boride gives various types of boranes especially $\ce{B4H10}$. See [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/jacs.7b06153?src=recsys) and [here](http://etheses.dur.ac.uk/6437/1/6437_3737.PDF?UkUDh:CyT) for reference.

Comment: @Maurice I think there is something even more strange.  We are speaking of $\ce{Mg3B2}$, but does this even exist?  Magnesium-boron phase diagram I've seen show no compound with stoichiometry $\ce{MgB_x}$ for any $x<2$.